# how to get list of orphan VHDs when storage account in locked for my subscription ID in Azure using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage-account

I am writing a PowerShell script which gets me the list of orphan `vhds` in azure but if I don't have access permission to storage account then am facing issue.

This works fine unless any of the storage accounts are locked, in which case it fails.

## Login to Azure Account

`Login-AzureRmAccount`

## Get Information about all the storage accounts

```
$SA = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount
```

## Get the VHDs in all the Storage accounts

```
$UMD = $SA | Get-AzureStorageContainer | Get-AzureStorageBlob | Where {$_.Name -like '*.vhd'}
```

## Filter out all the unlocked VHDs

```
$UMVHDS = $UMD | Where {$_.ICloudBlob.Properties.LeaseStatus -eq "Unlocked"}
```

## Get all the Managed Disks

```
$MVHDS = Get-AzureRmDisk
```

## Filter Managed Disks which do not have any Owner i.e Orphaned

```
$MVHD = $MVHDS | Where {$_.OwnerId -eq $null}
```

## Get all the objects with No Parent

```
$RmDiskInfo = foreach ($UMVHD in $UMVHDS)
{
    $StorageAccountName = if ($UMVHD.ICloudBlob.Parent.Uri.Host -match '([a-z0-9A-Z]*)(?=\.blob\.core\.windows\.net)') {$Matches[0]}
    $StorageAccount = $SA | Where { $_.StorageAccountName -eq $StorageAccountName }

    $Property = [ordered]@{
        AbsoluteUri = $UMVHD.ICloudBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
        LeaseStatus = $UMVHD.ICloudBlob.Properties.LeaseStatus;
        LeaseState = $UMVHD.ICloudBlob.Properties.LeaseState;
        StorageType = $StorageAccount.Sku.Name;
        StorageAccountName = $StorageAccountName;
        ResourceGroupName = $StorageAccount.ResourceGroupName
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Property
}
```

## Export Unamanged Disks to a CSV

```
$RmDiskInfo | Export-Csv -Path '.\UnusedUnmanagedVHDs.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

## Export Managed Disks to a CSV

```
$MVHD | Export-Csv -Path '.\UnusedManagedVHDs.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

**Error:**
Error : Get-AzureStorageContainer : The scope '/subscriptionsxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-bea7-31faae224077/resourceGroups/Test-RG-BlobDeletion/provid ers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/str1test' cannot perform write operation because following scope(s) are locked

Comment: Error : Get-AzureStorageContainer : The scope '/subscriptions/4f98b0d0-a2bd-4389-bea7-31faae224077/resourceGroups/Test-RG-BlobDeletion/provid
ers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/str1test' cannot perform write operation because following scope(s) are locked:

Answer (score 0):

To read, list the content of a container you have to use the key linked to that storage account, ex:

```
 $ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName <name> -StorageAccountKey <key>
Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $ctx
```

More information about access to Blobs and containers can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources

Comment: the storage account am trying to access is locked because I don't have read access for my profile.
Error : Get-AzureStorageContainer : The scope '/subscriptions/4f98b0d0-a2bd-4389-bea7-31faae224077/resourceGroups/Test-RG-BlobDeletion/provid ers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/str1test' cannot perform write operation because following scope(s) are locked:

Comment: you won't be able to read the content of a container to list it if you don't have read access. you have to ask the onwer for an access key even if it is a temporary one for your script to work.

Comment: I have 60 storage accounts, I want to retrieve the list of orphan VHDs within a storage account to which I have read access.